# Prove that $G(n,m)\rightarrow \gamma (G)\leq n$.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices. Let $\gamma(G)$ denote the dominating number of $G$. Show that $\gamma (G)\leq n$.

Comment: You should include the definition of $G(\cdot,\cdot)$ and $\gamma(\cdot)$. Is $G$ a function? Is $G$ the graph? What about the symbol $\rightarrow$?

Comment: @par 11 $G$ is a graph and $\rightarrow$ means implies.

Comment: What about $G(\cdot,\cdot)$ and $\gamma(\cdot)$?

Comment: @par 11. $G$ is a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ is the order of the edges in each vertex while $\gamma$ is the domination number of $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by $V(G)$ the vertex set of $G$ (with $|V(G)|=n$). Note
that $V(G)$ is trivially a dominating set. Since
$$
\gamma(G)=\min\left\{ \left|S\right|\colon S\text{ is a dominating set}\right\} ,
$$
the claim follows.

You should read [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DominationNumber.html) to learn about dominating sets, as I get the feeling that you have yet to do any self-studying on the topic.

Comment: I edited your original question to give you an idea of how to ask questions on Math.SE. Normally, you would also show the reader what you have tried/what didn't work/etc. (it is considered bad etiquette to post questions without showing what you have tried).